# Woocommerce display one category on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

All the products that have been uploaded to my shopping site belong to 2 parents categories. On the product page, I want to show only one. How do I specify only one category and the sub-category that it belongs to?

Example: Product 1 belongs to

- Parent Cat A and Child Cat A1
- Parent Cat B and Child Cat B1

How do I show only Parent CatB and Child Cat B1 on the product page?

**Meta.php**

```
<?php
    $size = count( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
    echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
    ?>
```

Comment: You could try linking directly to that category url. Something like yoururl.com/shop/product-category/parent-catB/

Comment: @redleaf, while parent CAT B is fixed, there are many children CATB1, CATB2, etc. How can I link them to all esp since it should display child cat related to that product?